# Nvidia Prime, Optimus laptop: how is 20.04 doing?

Tags: nvidia, dell, nvidia-optimus, xps, nvidia-prime

I am currently on elementary OS latest everything, I have an XPS 9550 with Intel integrated graphics and Nvidia discrete GPU (latest BIOS, January 2020).

With Nvidia drivers 435.21 (the latest stable ones available in my Software Center), I have my control panel where I can choose the dGPU or iGPU. But no On-demand mode, where the OS is deciding what to use.

Second problem is that while picking iGPU my selection is kept between boot cycles/suspend, the actual dGPU is not shut down, hence battery life is around 4-5 hours.

I found a little script I run at every boot (the old BB Switch) that can actually turn off the dGPU properly. I then get back my 8-10 hours of battery (I have the 84 WHr one).

**My question is:**

How 20.04 deals with all this? Does it actually turns off the dGPU properly with no extra command needed? Is the On-demand option available in the Nvidia control panel?

Thank you.